# Scala How to pass by reference for accumulator?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, accumulator

I am trying to update the accumulator inside a function but need to know the value of updated accumulator value outside the function which returns a different value(based on the function's property)

I am doing :

```
def test(value: Any, counter : Accumulator[Double]): String = {
    try {
     // do something 
        counter+= 1
        println("counter = "+ counter)
      }
    }
    return string
  }
```

when I call :

```
val counter : Accumulator[Double] = sc.accumulator(0, "COUNTER")
test(A, counter)
println(counter)
```

The counter inside the function is getting updated properly but not the one outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

> Accumulator are write-only variables for executors. They can be added to by executors and read by the driver only.

In your code, the `+=` is called in the `driver`, so you should invoke it in `executors`.

If you only need to call `test` once, you can use something like:

```
sc.parallelize(Array(1)).foreach(x => test(x, counter))
```

Comment: I need to call test for all the rows in Dataframe. I using this : df.rdd.map({do somthing...  test(..)}}